# PHP mysql if else

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to write an `if else` statement dependent on the value of a mySQL field.

Basically, in the awards table, if the `id_project` is **PRJ000** then I want the `$tempID` and `$tempProjectName` to be different values.

Right now this code runs but the results on the page are all following the `"else"` code block, which makes me think I've set up the `"if"` wrong. Any advice?

```
<?PHP
$query  = "SELECT * FROM `awards` ";
$query  .= "WHERE `active` = '1' ";
$query  .= "ORDER BY `date` DESC ";
$query  .= "LIMIT $idStart, 10 "; 
$result = mysql_query($query); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $query2  = "SELECT * FROM `projects` ";
    $query2  .= "WHERE `id_fm` = '".$row["id_project"]."' AND `active` = '1' ";
    $result2 = mysql_query($query2); 
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
    if($row["id_project"] == "PRJ000"){
        $tempID = "#";
        $tempProjectName = "General";
    }
    else {
        $tempID = $row2["id_x"];
        $tempProjectName = $row2["title"];
    }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: What is the value of `$row["id_project"]`?

Comment: Syntactically it is fine. What are some of the values `$row["id_project"]` has at each iteration?

Comment: Sorry if this doesn't quite answer your questions, but $row["id_project"] is set to the value of the field in the mySQL table. When I echo $row["id_project"] it correctly outputs as other project numbers ) like PRJ012, PRJ0134, etc, but when included in the if statement it doesn't work.

Comment: Dont use mysql drivers they are deprecated ages ago and will be removed. Use mysqli or PDO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I misunderstood your code and made mistake in last answer, replacing with updated code

```
<?php
$query  = "SELECT * FROM `awards` ";
$query  .= "WHERE `active` = '1' ";
$query  .= "ORDER BY `date` DESC ";
$query  .= "LIMIT $idStart, 10 "; 
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$projectId = $row["id_project"]; //Set a variable here and use later
    $query2  = "SELECT * FROM `projects` ";
    $query2  .= "WHERE `id_fm` = '$projectId' AND `active` = '1' ";
    $result2 = mysql_query($query2); 
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
    if($projectId == "PRJ000"){
        $tempID = "#";
        $tempProjectName = "General";
    }
    else {
        $tempID = $row2["id_x"];
        $tempProjectName = $row2["title"];
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks! unfortunately that didn't work. While it looks like $row["id_project"] is set, $row2["id_project"] has no values. What's the best way to rewrite the code given this issue?

Comment: I updated the answer, i misunderstood the code, my bad

Comment: by the way you can do this with more simple query by join both tables

Answer (score 0):

insted row to row2

```
   if($row2["id_project"] == "PRJ000"){
        $tempID = "#";
        $tempProjectName = "General";
    }
    else {
        $tempID = $row2["id_x"];
        $tempProjectName = $row2["title"];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you collected all the rows from the initial query (with a `foreach` or with the  [iterator_to_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-to-array.php) function, then you could loop over that simple array of data, and do the internal query at your leisure.

It would also make debugging easier, as you can just dump the rows between the searches easily.

In the long term, you could convert the query to `JOIN` the projects table to the awards table, based on `id_project = id_fm`, and so just have the project-specific data returned on its own for any further processing.